# Add Sum total of Products in a Cart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a rookie problem, and that is adding the sum total from an object (Cart) in my cart page before I go check out.[image: a busy cat]

#### Every time I navigate from one screen to the other the amount keeps going up[image: a busy cat 2]

#### I want the total amount to be 159, or the correct amount if i add more products

### [SourceCode](https://gist.github.com/acedesigns/2cd87e14b8e040eb0be71c6c11b1d8fa)

Comment: Please share the sample code not the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this piece of code:

```
this.cartItems.forEach((value, index) => {
    this.totalAmount += parseInt(value.amount);
});
```

with this:

```
this.totalAmount = this.cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return acc += item.amount;
}, 0);
```

In the first case you add a new value to already existing value. And in the `reduce` version it should rewrite the `totalAmount`.

Comment: In your case you are not considering `data.quantity` field. without this `totalAmount` is wrong.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda my example solves the original OP's issue. The quantity thing is another one. And you basically just posted the same answer as me, try not to do it in the future as it clutters the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Complete working example find out here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3iuwny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You just need to calculate cart amount using reduce() array function.

```
this.total = this.cart.reduce( (acc,curVal) => {
    return acc + (curVal.amount * curVal.quantity); 
     //this.temp.push( curVal.amount * curVal.quantity);
  },0)
```